# Adding user to a registry file & give it a permission using the command line or through C#?

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, permissions, registry

How can I add a new user in the registry & give it a permission to read or write for a specific file in the registry, using the command line...

Thanks..

**Edited:**

Or in C#, Which one can I do it easily, its fine with me... Since, the registry will be created & then the permission should be given during the c# code... All this I need it during coding....

for that reason, I just need a way to do that easily either by using the command line(calling it through C#) or from the C# it self...

I hope everything now clear ;)

Comment: I would not suggest trying to add a user with code.  I do not believe Microsoft has expose the ability to do so, even if you found a way that worked, it would be very hard to support.

Comment: unfortunately, I will know the user during the code.So, I can't add it before running the program. I need to do it automatically not manually. Since, I'm doing a setup file & I want everything automatically. If you have a better way, please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to create a Windows user account? If so, you would use the [`NetUserAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370649(VS.85).aspx) function or the [`NET USER`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251394) command from the command line.

If you need any more information, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: No, to be more specific. I need to add the user"DefaultAppPool" for the registry I will create it(during the code) & give it a read access. I'm doing that. Since, I want to use "aspset_reg" to generate a user & password and add it to a registry. So, I have to give it a read permission since i'm putting the tag that the "aspset_reg" generated in the "web.config" page. I hope it's clear now.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .reg file which holds registry information and just execute it from the command line or double click it.

But you will have to build a long long file with a lot of information in order to add a user to the OS.

Comment: I doubt that user information is stored solely in the registry. At the very least the user would also need a profile.

Comment: I think this will not work with me. Since, I'm doing all this in C# code, and the registry will be created during the running the code. So, during the code, the registry should be created & given the permission after that(adding user & then given it the permission)... So, I think this will not works.